# Loading a file no long works on iOS but works on android

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm storing an image in `persistentDataPath + @"/p.png"` and trying to load it in another method, it works in the editor, on Android and it also works when loading the image into the UI, my issue is that when I hit the share and save buttons, I get this error: `(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)`. I have searched up and down my code but I can't see any naming issues or discrepancies and I am at a bit of a loss. It worked fine previously and has worked in other projects also.

Native.cs

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE
private void ShareScreenShot()
{
    isProcessing = true;
    gameObject.GetComponent<NativeShare> ().Share ("", Application.persistentDataPath + @"/p.png", "", "");
    isProcessing = false;
}

public void SaveImageToStorage()
{
    isProcessing = true;
    Texture2D tex2D = null;
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + @"/p.png");
    tex2D.LoadImage (bytes);
    tex2D.Apply ();
    ScreenshotManager.SaveImage (tex2D, "image", "png");
    isProcessing = false;
}
#endif
```

CaptureScreen.cs

```
public void MakeSquarePNG()
{
    renderMaterial = renderObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

    GetPhotoSizes();   

    rendCam.aspect = 1;

    RenderTexture rendTex = new RenderTexture(Width, Height, 24);

    Texture2D tex2D = new Texture2D(Width, Height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    rendCam.targetTexture = rendTex;

    rendCam.Render();

    RenderTexture.active = rendTex;

    tex2D.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), 0, 0);

    RenderTexture.active = null;
    rendCam.targetTexture = null;

    byte[] bytes;

    bytes = tex2D.EncodeToPNG();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + @"/p.png", bytes);
}
```

*EDIT: added the full error from xCode*

```
NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.

at CropDragging.scaleFromPosition (Vector3 scale, Vector3 fromPos) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at CropDragging.Update () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 



(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

The classes specified in the null reference exception are completely unrelated to the issue, which is why I'm so confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Edit 2:*

As per JeanLuc's request I have pasted the class to a pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/Wdqz8wLr

Comment: I know now what this error is. It just says to you that filename that caused exception won't be printed as this feature is not implemented in il2cpp iOS.

Comment: what is the error message above `(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)` ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, The errors above are in completely unrelated scripts so I assumed they weren't part of the issue, I have updated the question with the full error.

Comment: Maybe in CropDragging.scaleFromPosition(...) you're accessing a variable that is not set yet, because of an undefined Script Execution Order, which could be different on iOS then on Android. could you show that code?